# How can we send html tags in onesignal?

Tags: html, push-notification, message, onesignal

I need to send messages to clients using onesignal from my webservice based on vb.net. Those messages are sent between html tags like : `<html><body>message<a href="...">link</a>text`, but whenever I try to send it through one signal i got this error:

```
System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (pushMessage=&quot;message&lt;a&gt;link&lt;/a&gt;text&quot;).
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateHttpValueCollection(HttpValueCollection collection, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HtmlFormParameterReader.Read(HttpRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

Can someone suggest a solution to send html data through onesignal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error appears to be happening on your server side, and not from OneSignal.

Here is Microsoft's guide on this error message: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestvalidationexception(v=vs.110).aspx

The Remarks section in the link above explains how to resolve this, to quote:

> Constraining and validating user input is essential in a Web
>   application to prevent hacker attacks that rely on malicious input
>   strings. Cross-site scripting attacks are one example of such hacks.
>   Other types of malicious or undesired data can be passed in a request
>   through various forms of input. By limiting the kinds of data that is
>   passed at a low level in an application, you can prevent undesirable
>   events, even when programmers who are using your code do not put the
>   proper validation techniques in place.
>
> Request validation detects
>   potentially malicious client input and throws this exception to abort
>   processing of the request. A request abort can indicate an attempt to
>   compromise the security of your application, such as a cross-site
>   scripting attack. It is strongly recommended that your application
>   explicitly check all input regarding request aborts. However, you can
>   disable request validation by setting the validateRequest attribute in
>   the directive to false, as shown in the following example: `<%@ Page validateRequest="false" %>` To disable request validation for your
>   application, you must modify or create a Web.config file for your
>   application and set the validateRequest attribute of the pages section
>   to false, as shown in the following example:

```
<configuration>   
  <system.web> 
    <pages validateRequest="false" />    
  </system.web>  
</configuration>
```

> To disable request validation for all applications
>   on your server, you can make this modification to the Machine.config
>   file.